# get instance fields from a TypeORM entity class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have an `typeorm` entity of the following form:

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

Now I am looking to get the instance fields from this entity class into an array,
like below:

```
['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'isActive']
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried the following but with no help:

```
class Me extends User{
    constructor() {
        super()     
    }
}

const me = new Me()
console.log(Object.keys(me)) // []
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
const userProps = getConnection()
  .getMetadata(User)
  .ownColumns
  .map(column => column.propertyName);
```

This means that you obtain metadata from an entity if you take the class function (AKA constructor) and use the `.getMetadata` method on the DB connection.

Reference:

[Get all properties from a entity #1764](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1764#issuecomment-468056409)

Answer (score 0):

Give initial values in your User class to the properties. They are null now, Object.keys wont list them. Try this:

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number = 0;

    @Column()
    firstName: string = "";

    @Column()
    lastName: string = "";

    @Column()
    isActive: boolean = false;
}
```

Alternative solution is when you fill the attrs manually:

```
const user = new User();
user.id = 0;
user.firstName = "";
user.lastName = "";
user.isActive = false;
```

Comment: but won't it get's affected on the database or something? This is typeorm entity class we are talking about

Comment: I use this solution (with postgres) and I have never had problems. Unfortunately the "default" option in @Column decorator only fills the attribute when you save the entity (to the db). Perhaps you can use an alternative solution if the first one is not familiar and you would like to list the keys before saving to db. See my edited answer.